# Show that the covariance operator of a Gaussian measure is uniquely determined and nonnegative

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, covariance, gaussian-measure

**Remark**: Feel free to assume $E=\mathbb R^d$, $d\in\mathbb N$, if it helps you to answer my question.

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $R:E'\to E$ be symmetric ($\langle R\varphi_1,\varphi_2\rangle=\langle R\varphi_2,\varphi_1\rangle$ for all $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in E'$) and $\rho$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ with characteristic function $$\hat\rho(\varphi)=e^{-\frac{\langle R\varphi,\:\varphi\rangle}2}\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in E'\tag1.$$

> How can we show that
>
> 1. $R$ is nonnegative ($\langle R\varphi,\varphi\rangle\ge0$ for all $\varphi\in E'$);
> 2. $R$ is uniquely determined?

Both claims are made in [Proposition 2.4.4.1 of *Structural Aspects in the Theory of Probability*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LtVpDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%22both+equalities+being+valid+for+all%22&source=bl&ots=JFvKLqtFq1&sig=ACfU3U0SHptAqGXL9U88O4OA709B2Rnlcw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihqejerZLzAhWmMewKHdVuCA0Q6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22both%20equalities%20being%20valid%20for%20all%22&f=false):

[image]

We know that there is a unique $f\in C(E',\mathbb C)$ with $f(0)=0$ and $$\hat\rho=e^f\tag2.$$ This function is denoted by $\log\hat\rho$ and called the *distinguished logarithm* of $\hat\rho$.

I would like to show the uniqueness claim in (2.) by the already known uniqueness of $\log\hat\rho$. We clearly should have $\log\hat\rho=-\frac{\langle R,\;\cdot\;\rangle}2$, but as you can see the book is claiming that $\log\hat\rho=-\langle R,\;\cdot\;\rangle$. Is this a typo?

In any case, I don't understand how the uniqueness immediately follows from this. And while the inequality shown for $\hat\rho$ is clear, how does it yield (1.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write $E^*$ instead of $E'$ (assuming it's the dual space). I'm assuming that by pairings $\langle R\varphi_1,\varphi_2\rangle$ we mean $\varphi_2 ( R\varphi_1)$.

**Lemma**. If $R,S: E^* \to E$ are such that for all $\varphi,\psi \in E^*$ we have $\langle R\varphi,\psi \rangle = \langle S\varphi,\psi \rangle$ then $R-S$ is a zero mapping. In other words, $R$ is uniquelly determined by $\langle R\varphi,\psi\rangle$ for any $\varphi,\psi \in E^*$.

Proof. Fixing $\varphi \in E^*$, we see that by linearity of $\psi \in E^*$ we get $\psi \big( R\varphi - S\varphi \big) = 0$. Since $\psi$ is arbitrary, by Hahn Banach theorem (the only element vanishing on every functional is a zero element) we get $0=R\varphi - S\varphi = (R-S)\varphi$ for any $\varphi \in E^*$. Since $\varphi$ is arbitrary, we see that $R-S$ is a zero mapping $\square$

(2). Hence as we see, it is sufficient to determine $\langle R\varphi,\psi\rangle$  for any $\psi,\varphi \in E^*$. Since $R$ is symmetric, values $\langle R\varphi,\psi \rangle$ are uniquelly determined by values of $\langle R(\varphi+\psi),\varphi+\psi\rangle$,$\langle R(\varphi-\psi),\varphi-\psi\rangle$, in other words by values $\langle R\eta,\eta \langle$ for any $\eta \in E^*$.

Note that $-2\log(\hat p(\eta)) = \langle R\eta,\eta \rangle$, so since $\hat p$ is itself unique, then so is $-2\log(\hat p)$, which means that $\eta \to \langle R\eta,\eta \rangle$ is unique, which by the above discussion and lemma, is sufficient to say that $R$ is itself unique.

(1). As for the non-negativeness, it's easier. Note that $\hat p(\varphi) \le 1$ for any $\varphi \in E^*$. Taking logarithm, we arrive at $\log(\hat p (\varphi)) \le 0$. By multiplying by $-2$, we get $ \langle R\varphi,\varphi \rangle = -2\ln(\hat p(\varphi)) \ge 0 $. Since $\varphi \in E^*$ was arbitrary, we can deduce the non-negativeness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (a) When you write $-2\log(\hat p(\eta)) = \langle R\eta,\eta \rangle$, the function evaluation $\log(\hat p(\eta)$ is actually the evaluation of the function $f$ (in the question, which I wrote is denoted by $\log\hat p$) at $\eta$; NOT the evaluation of the composition $\log\circ\hat p$ for the principal branch $\log$ of the complex logarithm, right? (b) Just to be sure: So you agree with me that $\log\hat\rho=-\langle R,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ is wrong and must be a typo in the book, right?

Comment: Yes, as for the (b) it's just typo, indeed from equation $\hat{p}(\varphi) = \exp(-\frac{\langle R\varphi,\varphi \rangle}{2})$, by taking log you obtain $-2\log \hat{p}(\varphi) = \langle R\varphi,\varphi \rangle$. As for the question a), I don't quite understand.  In my view, $\log (\hat{p}(\eta))$ is the same as $(\log \circ \hat{p}) (\eta)$ which is the same as $\log \hat p(\eta)$, it's just the matter of notation, all of those formulas work like, firstly evaluate $\hat{p}$ in $\eta$, then evaluate $\log$ of $\hat{p}(\eta)$ (it is in fact a standard logarithm, function $\hat{p}$ is real)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Regarding (b): That's the important point: $\hat p$ is real-valued and hence $\log(\hat p)$ is *actually* the composition of the natural logarithm and $\hat p$. However, I'm not sure whether you've got that in mind, but please note that in in general the characteristic function $\hat\mu$ of a general probability measure $\mu$ is complex-valued and hence (assuming $\hat\mu\ne0$) $\log\hat\mu$ is the *distinguished* logarithm of $\hat\mu$ which is of the form $\log\hat\mu=\ln|\hat\mu|+{\rm i}\Im\hat\mu$, where $\Im\hat\mu$ is a continuous argument function.

Comment: I'm certainly sure that characteristic function can be complex valued (i.e any non-symmetric probability distribution on $\mathbb R$ have complex c.f), but anyway $(\log \circ \hat{\mu})(x)$ and $\log \hat{\mu}(x)$ is really the same, both means (in your terminology) value $\ln |\hat{\mu}(x)| + i\Im \hat{\mu}(x)$

Comment: I'm sorry, but no, it's *not* the same in general. If $\varphi$ is a general characteristic function, it might take values in $(-\infty,0]$, but the principal branch of the complex algorithm is only continuous on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$. (Maybe the crucial point you're missing is that the *distinguished* logarithm $\log\varphi$ of $\varphi$ is required to be continuous.)